# Error trying to access the sharepoint online list REST API using powershell

Tags: powershell, api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I followed this tutorial
[https://blog.vgrem.com/2015/01/27/consuming-the-sharepoint-online-rest-api-from-powershell-part-2/][1]

The above link showed how to get the token and how to call the rest API in SharePoint online using powershell, but the problem is. I am getting a

403 Forbidden error when the endpoint is

```
$WebUri = "https://mycustomname.sharepoint.com"
$endpointUri = "$WebUri/sites/VirtualName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('$ListTitle')"
```

When I changed the endpoint to the below I get 401 Unauthorized

```
$endpointUri = "$WebUri/sites/VirtualName/lists/getbytitle('$ListTitle')"
```

The permission XML I tried a few different links int he scope but nothing helped.
Appdomain - localhost
Redirect URl - https://mycustomname.sharepoint.com/sites/VirtualName

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">  
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://mycustomname.sharepoint.com/sites/VirtualName/Lists/mylistname" 
    Right="Manage" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The app permission request scope url could only be these:

1. http://sharepoint/content/tenant
2. http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection
3. http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web
4. http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list
   [image]
   [add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint)

   ```
   $username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
   $password = "Password"
   $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
   Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential $cred
   Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false
   ```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried what you suggested. http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web in the permission xml
Still getting the same issue.
Is the redirect URL correct ?
Redirect URl - https://mycustomname.sharepoint.com/sites/VirtualName

This is set in the code do I need to change the below URL or does it look correct?
$WebUri = "https://mycustomname.sharepoint.com"
$endpointUri = "$WebUri/sites/VirtualName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('$ListTitle')"

Comment: Is your office365 tenant created recenly?

Comment: Hi, yes I do get the token back successfully.

Comment: When you say recent do you mean for a few days ? I have it over month.

Comment: Try to run Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false.

Comment: I got this error when trying to the set-SPOTenant
Set-SPOTenant : No connection available. Use Connect-SPOService before running this CmdLet.
The script above didn't have a function defined for that.

Comment: Check the updated.Ang you need to update the sahrepoint online managed shell to the latest version.

Comment: I used the Pnp and that worked. The whole issue I was trying not to use these modules. I am trying to run this from linux pwsh 7. So I was just trying to use the OAUTH2 and try to access it from that angle. Do you know if this could run on Linux. I checked online so far the libs do not work on Linux . I tried the pnp fput go errors on the login. Any advice or there is no way to do it on Linux ?